# Why can't I update my iPad to iOS 6 or 7?

Tags: ipad, ios

This is my first iPad, I can't figure this out - when I go to settings>general>software update I get "iOS 5.1.1 Your software is up to date"

I have iOS 5.1.1, also I have ubuntu on my PC (I see some advice about using iTunes, but I don't have OS X or Windows on my PC)

Answer (score 4):

Which version of the iPad do you have? Not every version is compatible with every version of iOS; in particular, the first-generation iPad cannot be upgraded to iOS 6+. If that's what you've got, 5.1.1 *is* the latest version your device supports.

See [this table on EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/ipad-faq/ipad-operating-system-info-update-cost-app-support.html) for details of which versions are compatible with which operating systems.